# SQL - Windows Policy

Tags: sql, windows, privileges, policy

How can I find out and set if an User is enabled or disabled using SQL commands? Same problem for windows policy enabled/disabled for an User.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LOGINPROPERTY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345412.aspx) - example -

```
SELECT LOGINPROPERTY('John3', 'IsLocked');
GO
```

You can use [sys.server_principals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) for checking enabled disabled -

```
SELECT * from sys.server_principals where "name" = 'loginname'
```